# What is the grammatical difference between "страстнейшей" and "страстнейшею"?

Tags: падежи

Compare these two constructions:

> Он полон страстнейше**й** силы.

> Он полон страстнейше**ю** силы.

What's going on here? As far as I can tell, both are feminine, "творительный падеж"...so why are there two options? Is the second an archaic form or does it have an actual usage that escapes me here?

Comment: Силы is genitive.

Comment: Down-voting, since you basically don't explain why exactly you consider both forms valid. Without context it looks like you are providing two sentences, one is just wrong - and then asking "what's going on here" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one seems wrong to me due to lack of agreement between noun an adjective.
Он полон страстнейшею силою (силой) is an option, since I think полон allows both творительный и родительный падежи

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Yaroslav. A follow-up question: Would you say that _силой_ is a normal form and _силою_ is a poetic one?

Comment: Something like that. I wouldn't say normal, I would say standard/unmarked vs poetic, meaning either higher register or one that can be used in poetry because of rhyme or metre restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Страстнейшая

Именительный падеж

Страстнейшая

Родительный падеж

**Страстнейшей**

Дательный падеж

Страстнейшей

Винительный падеж

Страстнейшую

Творительный падеж

**Страстнейшею**,
**Страстнейшей**

Предложный падеж

Страстнейшей

After **полон** you can use either

родительный падеж(genitive) полон чего? **страстнейшей силы**

or творительный (instrumental) полон чем? **страстнейшей силой**

and **страстнейшею силою /силой** ( this one is mostly used in poetry or folklore)

Compare a tale by Pushkin

Пришел невод с **одною** рыбкой,**непростою** рыбкой, **золотою**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, V.V. You kind of blew my mind with the distinction between _полон чего_ and _полон чем_ which I actually never considered. :)